# Blank Screen when running existing PHP website on localhost

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I’m trying to run php exsitng website on my localhost,
I’ve added DB under local phpmyadmin, I run XAMPP server,
I run php project n VS Code, but when I try to access the website it is just **BLANK SCREEN**.
I’ve tested to put some text in index.php before php code begins and it shows up. Smth is preventing website to load, but I dont see any logs,
how can I debug?

Comment: Check the web server error logs, and/or run `php -l index.php` (at the command line) to see if it may have syntax error(s).

Comment: enable error_reporting as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: No syntax errors detected in Index.php, also checked error_reporting its enabled. Still Blank Screen

Answer (score 0):

Your php.ini has commented out `display_errors=On`, you need to uncomment it. Also make sure that the `error_reporting` is uncommented and has a valid value.

error_reporting examples the XAMPP php.ini:

> ; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
>
> ; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
>
> ; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

The location of your php.ini depends on your OS and XAMPP version, but generally the folder where your XAMPP is installed contains a symlink to it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer, though I've checked and all seems to be good, display_errors=ON, error_reporting has valid values..   It should be something else